# Scraping dynamic website with filters python

Tags: python, web-scraping, dynamic

i want to scrape a table in a web site : https://www.feedtables.com/fr/content/table-dry-matter. The probleme is that there are filtters to use in order to have the data needed otherwise you only get the data rendered once entering the website! any help please!

this is the code i have used to scrape the table :

```
import requests
import bs4 
import pandas as pd

URL = 'https://www.feedtables.com/fr/content/table-dry-matter'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text,'lxml')
cases = soup.find('table', class_= 'views-table sticky-enabled cols-16')
headers=[]
for i in cases.find_all('th'):
    headers.append(i.text.strip())

Data=[]
for i in cases.find_all('td'):
    Data.append(i.text.strip())

chunks = [Data[x:x+16] for x in range(0, len(Data), 16)]
chunks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There are different approaches

1. As burak mentioned [selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65612844/14460824) to automate things
2. Go with your `requests` and add `parameters` to your url as there are `feed_cat` and `parameter_cat` that you can get from the `select` above the table. **Update - Take a look at the Edit part**

My example loops over the options of the `feed_cat` selectbox by

`soup.find('select',attrs={'name': 'feed_cat'}).find_all('option')[1:3]`
(it just take the second and third option to demonstrate)

Then it `requests` with these parameters like that

`page = requests.get(url+'?feed_cat='+option['value']+'&parameter_cat=All', headers=headers)`

In the end you can loop over data to generate your data frames.

Attention: The simple approache to get all the data in one request `https://www.feedtables.com/fr/content/table-dry-matter?feed_cat=All&parameter_cat=All` wont work, you will get an server error.

**Example for requests**

```
import bs4
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.feedtables.com/fr/content/table-dry-matter"
headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}

page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text,'lxml')

data = []

for option in soup.find('select',attrs={'name': 'feed_cat'}).find_all('option')[1:3]:
    page = requests.get(url+'?feed_cat='+option['value']+'&parameter_cat=All', headers=headers)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text,'lxml')
    
    cases = soup.select_one('table.views-table.sticky-enabled')
    
    th=[]
    td=[]
    for i in cases.find_all('th'):
        th.append(i.text.strip())
        
    for row in cases.find_all('tr')[1::2]:
        td.append([i.get_text(strip=True) for i in row.find_all('td')])   
            
    
    data.append({'cat' : option.text, 'headers':th, 'data':td})

df=pd.DataFrame(data[0]['data'], columns=data[0]['headers'])
df
```

**Output (execute the example looks better ;))**

```
Matière première    MS %    MAT %   CB %    MGr %   MM %    MMins % NDF %   ADF %   Lignine %   ... GluDIS volaille g/kg    GlyDIS volaille g/kg    SerDIS volaille g/kg    ProDIS volaille g/kg    CED MJ/kg   ConsP g P/kg    CC g CO2eq/kg   Acid. mol H+eq/kg   Eutrophisation g PO4---eq/kg    OS m²yr/kg
0   Avoine  100 10.8    13.1    5.4 2.9 1.2 35.7    16.3    2.6 ... 15  4.2 4   4.9 3.02›››3.23›››  3.32›››3.32›››  555›››566›››    0.0139›››0.014›››   61.23›››61.52›››    0.0002›››0.0002›››
1   Avoine décortiquée  100 12.8    4.5 3.1 2.5 1.2 12.8    5.3 1.9 ... 19.9    5.2 5.1 6.3                     
2   Avoine floconnée    100 10.8    13.1    5.4 2.9 1.2 35.7    16.3    2.6 ... 15  4.2 4   4.9                     
3   Blé dur 100 16.4    3   2   2.1 0.05    15.9    4.2 1.3 ... 48.2    5.5 7.2 16.3
```

### Edit

Improved my example to the following much shorter that is using `pd.read_html()`

```
import bs4
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.feedtables.com/fr/content/table-dry-matter"
headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}

page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text,'lxml')

df_list = []

for url in [url+'?feed_cat='+option['value']+'&parameter_cat=All' for option in soup.find('select',attrs={'name': 'feed_cat'}).find_all('option')][1:3]:
    df_list.append(pd.read_html(url)[0])

df = df_list[0].dropna(how='all')
df
```

Comment: Wow!!! Man, this is why i love programming community! much love bro ! you rock! thanks a lot!

Comment: Done dear! Thanks a lot again for the edit!

Answer (score 0):

You can not handle it with bs4. But you can do easily with selenium.

```
#Download chromedriver from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads  
#pip install selenium


    import time, os
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    
    chromedriver = "C:\\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver"
    os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver

    url_head = 'https://www.google.com/search?q="HOW+TO+USE+SELENIUM"'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
    driver.get(url)
```

This is how you can connect. then you can click with like this.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//html/body/div[1]/div/ul/li[3]').click()
```

For more info please check : https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: Thanks a lot der burak. that means i should use selenium for these kind of web sites! thanks again for your answe!